# Complex Integral Path Dependency

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a hard time understanding how one can take the following complex integral. $$\int |z|^2 \, dz.$$
Why is it not path independent. Wouldn't the hypotheses of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and Cauchy's Theorem apply since the function is continuous, has an anti-derivative, and is differentiable on a domain containing the path?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the function $f(z)=|z|^2$ would have an anti-derivative $F$. Then we would have that $F$ is holomorphic, hence $f$ would be holomorphic.

But it is easy to see that $f$ is not holomorphic (Cauchy - Riemann !)

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(z) = |z|^2$ is not differentiable w.r.t. the complex variable $z$.  This can be shown here by seeing if $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann conditions, which can be written:
$$
{\partial \over \partial \overline{z}} f =(?) 0.
$$
Well, writing $f(z) = z \overline{z}$ shows that the Cauchy-Riemann conditions do not hold, hence the function fails to be holomorphic.

(See pages 67-68 in this book: https://books.google.com/books?id=xUHDAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=cartan+theory+of+analytic+functions+of+one+several+complex&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie3aKQyZ3QAhXpsVQKHUJNDh4Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=Cauchy%20conditions&f=false)